# Sorted output of a joined MySQL result in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

Doing an allnighter on a project and my mind is blank atm... Simple question really:

I have two MySQL tables, product and category. Each product belongs to exactly one category. Every category has several products.

```
SELECT 
  p.uid as product_uid, p.name_NL as product_name, p.price as product_price,
  c.uid as category_uid, c.name_NL as category_name 
FROM 
  product p, category c
WHERE
  p.category_uid = c.uid
```

This gives me a nice overview of all products in their respective category. My question is about **outputting this data** on the page. I'm aiming for this:

```
<h1>Category name</h1>
<p>Product in this category</p>
<p>Other product in this category</p>

<h1>Next category</h1>
<p>Product in next category</p>
```

My mind is completely blank right now. How would one go about doing this?

I would like to avoid doing subqueries (if possible).

Kind regards,

M

Comment: How about selecting all the categories, then loop through them. In the loop, select all products in the category, and loop through those, outputting them.

Comment: So two queries then, storing their respective results in two arrays, and then working like that?

Comment: Two queries, one nested in the loop of the results of the first.

Comment: Isn't that too resource intensive? I've always thought that's a bad practice. What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about adding `ORDER BY category_uid` so that the products are ordered by category in your SQL query. Then using PHP, loop through each product (row) and when you encounter a new category, add a new header.

**Example:**

```
<?php

// ...

$previous_category_uid = null;

// Loop through each row.
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() )
{
  // If the category UID is not the same as the one from the previous row, add a header.
  if ( $previous_category_uid != $row['category_uid'] )
  {
    echo '<h1>' . $row['category_name'] . '</h1>';
    $previous_category_uid = $row['category_uid'];
  }
}
```

The benefit of this method is that you don't have to nest queries. A single query will suffice.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the most easily implementable solution for my current setup!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just need to use a `GROUP BY category_uid` ?

Comment: No, then I would only display 1 product from every category, while there could be several (if I'm not mistaken, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for alphabetical ordering for category names and products within each category:

```
SELECT 
  p.uid as product_uid, p.name_NL as product_name, p.price as product_price,
  c.uid as category_uid, c.name_NL as category_name 
FROM product p INNER JOIN category c ON p.category_uid = c.uid
ORDER BY category_name, product_name
```

This also converts your query's Cartesian product and `WHERE` to an inner join.

To output with the headers you want, just loop over the returned rows, and keep track of the category you're in. Whenever the category of the current row is different from the previous one, you print a new `h1` for the new category and update the stored "current" category.

Comment: Thank you. Is there in this case a big advantage using Inner Join? Is my way of connecting the tables a bad practice?

Comment: Specifying multiple tables in the `FROM` clause separated only by commas does a Cartesian product, which results in every possible combination of the rows from both tables. You then eliminate all the "extra" results with your `WHERE` clause. The inner join is designed for exactly this use case, and avoids the generation of all those intermediate "extra" rows. Query optimizers can sometimes detect your intent and avoid the Cartesian product, but an inner join is really what you want here.

Comment: Thank you, John, I'll be sure to do avoid these Cartesian joins then.

Comment: Also note, in case it's unclear: Francois' answer implements basically the exact strategy for creating the output that I described at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you have two options:

1. Get all the data at once (like you are doing currently) then use PHP to either pre-sort the data by category. Then do your output looping over this array. So 1 query, 2 + n loops (where n is the number of categories).
2. Get all your categories and then loop over those for output. In each iteration you will need to query all products for that loop. So 1 + n queries, 1 + n loops (where, again, n is the number of categories).

Option 2 might be more straightforward, but clearly there are more queries. In the end, it's your call.